# Colocar nome em coluna (sem nome) no python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Gostaria de saber como colocar o nome em uma coluna de um df no python, sendo que a mesma não possui nome.

após realizar a concatenação, conforme abaixo, verifiquei que no resultado não aparece o nome na coluna dos ativos.

```
volatility = pd.DataFrame(retornos.std(), columns=['Vol'])
media_retornos = pd.DataFrame(retornos.mean(), columns = ['Returns'])

risco_retorno = pd.concat([media_retornos, volatility], axis=1)
print (risco_retorno.head(5))
```

o resultado do print, é o mesmo da foto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de atualizar o nome para ficar com as colunas "Company", "Returns" e "Vol".

Comment: Atualizando, consegui criar um nova coluna, com o nome Company, utilizando o código:
risco_retorno.insert(loc=0, column = 'Company', value = tickers)

Porém, quando coloco para plotar, aparece somente a primeira empresa, que no caso seria VALE3.SA

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua coluna 'Company', após concatenar, tornou-se a indexacao.

Para ver/ler o nome do index no seu dataframe:   `risco_retorno.index.name`

Para renomear a sua coluna index: `risco_retorno.index.name = 'Company'`